# SugarCRM 7.6 filter with $and operator

Tags: rest, filter, sugarcrm

I am using the SugarCRM rest api to filter on records. I am trying to create a query, by setting a filter. The $or operator seems to work ok, but not the $and. So the following works -

```
$filter_arguments = array(
    "filter" => array(      
        array
        (
            '$or' => array
             (
                array(                    
                    "first_name" => array(
                        '$starts'=>"Joseph",
                        )
                    ),
                array(
                       "last_name" => array(
                          '$starts'=>"Man",
                        )
                ),
            ),
        ),        
    ),
    "max_num" => 5,
    "offset" => 0,
    "fields" => "name,description",
);
```

But the following fails

```
$filter_arguments = array(
    "filter" => array(      
        array
        (
            '$and' => array
             (
                array(                    
                    "first_name" => array(
                        '$starts'=>"Joseph",
                        )
                    ),
                array(
                       "last_name" => array(
                          '$starts'=>"Man",
                        )
                ),
            ),
        ),        
    ),
    "max_num" => 5,
    "offset" => 0,
    "fields" => "name,description",
);
```

that is, it returns an empty array, inspite of their being records. I have tried taking off the $and also (I believe this is the default), but that also returns an empty array. Some help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks okay to me.  Could you try using $and with other fields and see if you still have problems?  You could also try to do some detailed logging/debugging to examine the actual SQL query that's being run to make sure it's being created like you expect it to be.